# express.js error handling on http requests

Tags: node.js, express

How to handle errors in http requests?

Here the full error is returned to the client.. How to write the error to the log and return `Fatal error` to the client?

Express v4.4.4

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    domain = require('domain'),
    port = 3000;

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send('Fatal error!', 500);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var d = domain.create();
    d.on('error', function(err){
        console.error('Error', err);

        res.send('Fatal error!', 500);
    });
    d.add(req);
    d.add(res);
    d.run(function(){
        //  a is undefined
        a.ddd();

        res.send('Success!');
    });
})
.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port '+port);
});
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Comment: have updated my question.. still sending the error stack to the client

Comment: Buddy - 'app.use' is an example.

Comment: check the link for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .use for the error handler needs to be at the bottom, after the routes/handlers/middlewhare which may cause the errors.  Then from your other places, call next(error) instead of returning an error message directly

```
// this comes first
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){ // note the addition of next
    var d = domain.create();
    d.on('error', function(err){
        next(err); // pass the error on to the next middleware
    });
    // ... 
});

// this comes last
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send('Fatal error!', 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Error-handling middleware are defined just like regular middleware, however must be defined with an arity of 4, that is the signature (err, req, res, next):

[Express Error Handling](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)

**eg code:**

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```